# Does this is an onshell propagator?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams

This image is from [here](https://canvas.harvard.edu/files/936391/download?download_frd=1&verifier=x0zyaPHMxOvHCcrRCDqlHUqjT4stQ3tv0Z69Eohc) (page 6-7).
My question refers to Eq. 26 and 27
The denominator changed from $(p_1 -p_3)^2 - m^2$ to $p_3^2 - 2p_3p_1$.
So they used $p_1^2 = m^2$. But I thought, this relation is only valid for onshell particles. However, the propagator is offshell, and m is the mass of the propagator particle?

[image]

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the denominator the mass $m$ really refers to the on-shell rest mass of the propagator particle, e.g. in this case the electron. So therefore this step is totally valid.

Edit:

When deriving the propagator of a field, which can be read  e.g. in Peskin and Schroeder, the mass just is part of the propagator so it is valid whenever the propagator particle is massive

Comment: Thanks. And in which case this is not valid? How can I see if this valid or not?

Comment: But in case of the photonpropagator we dont even have a massterm in the propagator. So it is always valid?

Comment: Yes it is. I would recommend to read Chapter 3 of Peskin and Schroeder
https://books.google.de/books/about/An_Introduction_To_Quantum_Field_Theory.html?id=EVeNNcslvX0C&redir_esc=y